# How to pass multiple fq's with OR in SOLR

Tags: solr

In solr, If we pass two fq's by default it will take it as AND,  instead how to make it as or.

- For Example: fq=school:"srm"&fq=class:"first"
  This condition bydefault it will take it as and but how to pass OR condition for the same.

Thanks,
Subbarao.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solr 5.4 and later understands [filter syntax in the body of main query](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser#TheStandardQueryParser-DifferencesbetweenLuceneQueryParserandtheSolrStandardQueryParser) (search for "filter(...)" on the page). So, you can do:

> fq=filter(inStock:true) filter(price:[* TO 100])

You can also use variable substitutions to make these more readable by putting each filter into its own variable.

Several of these interesting concepts were well explained in the [Hoss' presentation at Lucene/Solr Revolution 2016](https://youtu.be/qTVi7eMGe1A).

Comment: Good point - I forgot about `filter()` (and yes, the presentation is a must watch). The correct solution would depend on how the different queries interact.

Answer (score 2):

Filters are applied independently, so if you want to have an OR filter, you'll have to apply it inside a single filter:

```
fq=school:"srm" OR class:"first"
```

Comment: Instead of this it should look like fq="school"&fq="first",  is there any way to do like this.

Comment: No, as I said - if you want to OR terms, you'll have to use a single filter. Filters are applied for _filtering_ a result set, i.e. a filter is something the existing result passes through. Either add the terms to your query or use a single filter for them.